# Maven POM version management for multiple maven projects

Tags: maven, pom.xml

In our projects, we have about 25 maven projects and each one of them contains at least 3 module projects and one parent POM.  So total is around (25 *4) 100 POM files.   Is there any easy way to maintain POM change version ?  So this task become tedious and boring task.  This must be common problem across the Software Development  ?

Does anyone have scripts or tool  to do this version change to handle following 3 cases ?

```
1)  
    <dependency>
      <groupId>THEGROUPID</groupId>
      <artifactId>THEARTIFACT</artifactId>
      <version>THE-VERSION</version>
    </dependency>

2)
    <dependency>
      <groupId>THEGROUPID</groupId>
      <artifactId>THEARTIFACT</artifactId>
      <version>$(version.number)</version>
    </dependency>
3)
  <parent>
    <groupId>THEGROUPID</groupId>
    <artifactId>THEARTIFACT</artifactId>
    <version>THE-VERSION</version>
  </parent>
```

We have 25 maven projects and each one have on each other (via parent pom but not cyclic dependency)  dependency, between them.  So When we change a version of one of the lib, it needs to be changed throughout out all the maven module parent POMs..... Hence, I was looking for tool that can achieve this across the rage of POMs not just one muti-module project (release plug-in will only release and ONE maven muti-module project.) I hope this will have better understanding of the problem..

Basically, I am looking for linux SED type of command but for specific groupid and artifactid.

Thanks,

Bmis13

Answer (score 6):

Put all the versions in the `<dependencyManagement>` in your parent pom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>THEGROUPID</groupId>
      <artifactId>THEARTIFACT</artifactId>
      <version>THE-VERSION</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Hereby, you do not need to add the `<version>` tag to your child poms.

Ref: [dependencyManagement](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) (scroll down)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`versions-maven-plugin`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html) with its `set` mojo:

```
cd <your-super-parent-pom>
mvn versions:set -DoldVersion=1-SNAPSHOT -DnewVersion=2-SNAPSHOT
```

This plugin however has some limitations. It does not cope with certain (complex) structures where pom inheritance is complex, and I am also not sure if it handles property references.

There is similar functionality inside [`maven-release-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/update-versions.html). It might have a slightly higher chance to work better, as it is used more frequently - and AFAIK the code is not shared - but I have no direct experience with this. I just observed *many* releases with correct version renumbering in quite difficult scenarios...

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my own tool to do this. It's called 'pommel' and you can get it here:

http://code.google.com/p/pommel/

You define a mapping file and run it from the command line i.e.

```
java -jar pommel-1.0.0.jar -iC:\Development\java\projects -mmapping.xml
```

The mapping file takes the form:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mappings>
  <mapping>
    <dependency-source>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>*</version>
    </dependency-source>
    <dependency-target>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency-target>
  </mapping>

</mappings>
```

This will replace all references to junit with the specified dependency target. Not you can use a wild card in the dependency source definition. It will apply the mapping to ALL pom files it find under the specified directory.